# Popup is not resizible

Tags: firefox-extensions, headers

When I open the modify header extension, it opens outside the monitor and I can only press the "OK" button; In other word I cannot see the button that are in the upper part of the pop-up.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [Modify Header by Gareth Hunt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/), its window is resizable. I tested it in Windows 10. So, do either of the following:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to force it snap to either the left or right side of the screen.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open its system menu. Then use Resize command and keyboard to resize it to fit in your screen.